# pandas, name of the column after a group by function

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a simple Pandas Dataframe named purchase_cat_df:

```
              email                cat
0  email1@gmail.com  Mobiles & Tablets
1  email2@gmail.com  Mobiles & Tablets
2  email1@gmail.com  Mobiles & Tablets
3  email3@gmail.com  Mobiles & Tablets
4  email3@gmail.com      Home & Living
5  email1@gmail.com      Home & Living
```

I'm grouping by the 'email' and and putting 'cat' in a list like this:

```
test = purchase_cat_df.groupby('email').apply(lambda x: list(x.cat))
```

but then my DataFrame test is:

```
email
email1@gmail.com    [Mobiles & Tablets, Mobiles & Tablets, Home & ...
email2@gmail.com                                  [Mobiles & Tablets]
email3@gmail.com                   [Mobiles & Tablets, Home & Living]
```

I lost the indexs and the name, how can I named the column 2?

Comment: I think you are getting a Series, not a DataFrame.

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is here, but I'd recommend calling `purchase_cat_df = purchase_cat_df.set_index('email')`  Then you can get your list by calling `purchase_cat_df.loc[emailX,'cat'].tolist()` calling without tolist() returns a series

Comment: Obviously the index no longer makes sense, since each output line is generated from multiple input lines with different indices.

Comment: thanks for your comment @ZJS I tried but I have the following error: "NameError: name 'emailX' is not defined"

Comment: Emailx was just an example to get whatever email that you wanted.  In other words it was a variable for any of the emails that existed in your pandas Email series

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep your original index, you were probably looking for something like this:

```
purchase_cat_df.groupby('email', as_index=False)
```

as_index=False keeps the original index. You can then continue to address the column by its name.

Answer (score 0):

As @BrenBarn mentioned in the comments, the column with the lists doesn't have a name, because you've got a `Series`, not a `DataFrame`.

Try this:

```
test = purchase_cat_df.groupby('email').apply({'cat': list})
```

which returns a `DataFrame` with `email` set as the index and `cat` as the name of the new column.

You can also use this when you have multiple columns you want to aggregate. See [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-different-functions-to-dataframe-columns) which has a few examples.