# Can we separate data using Unique ID in to the following format?

Tags: python-3.x, datatable, extract, data-manipulation

Current Format:

| **UNIQUE ID** | **NAME** | **AGE** | **DEP** | **RANK** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | John | 10 | 4th | 1 |
| 002 | Priya | 11 | 4th | 2 |
| 003 | Jack | 15 | 5th | 2 |
| 004 | Jill | 14 | 5th | 1 |

Expected Format:

| **UNIQUE ID** | **NAME** | COLUMN_NO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | John | 1 |
| 001 | 10 | 2 |
| 001 | 4th | 3 |
| 001 | 1 | 4 |
| 002 | Priya | 1 |
| 002 | 11 | 2 |
| 002 | 4th | 3 |
| 002 | 2 | 4 |

Comment: I want to transfer the current format data to the desired format using and extract it into an excel sheet using python.

Comment: In which format (database, XLSX, CSV, ...) is the source data available? Which package(s) do you need/want/must/must not use? Is pandas on the table? In any case: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Formal is XLSX,
Pandas is on the table. Packages used  pandas, split from re

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My starting point:

```py
>>> df
    UNIQUE ID   NAME    AGE  DEP   RANK
0           1   John     10  4th      1
1           2  Priya     11  4th      2
2           3   Jack     15  5th      2
3           4   Jill     14  5th      1
```

The basic transformation you need is provided by [`df.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html?highlight=stack#pandas.DataFrame.stack), which results in:

```
0  UNIQUE ID         1
   NAME           John
   AGE              10
   DEP             4th
   RANK              1
1  UNIQUE ID         2
   NAME          Priya
[...]
```

However, you want column `UNIQUE ID` to be treated separately. This can be accomplished by making it the index:

```
>>> df.set_index('UNIQUE ID').stack()
UNIQUE ID
1          NAME     John
           AGE         10
           DEP       4th
           RANK         1
2          NAME    Priya
           AGE         11
           DEP       4th
           RANK         2
```

The last missing bit are the column names: you want them renamed to numbers. This could be accomplished two different ways: a) by re-assigning `df.columns` (after having moved column UNIQUE ID to the index first):

```
df = df.set_index('UNIQUE_ID')
df.columns = range(1, 5)
```

or b) by `df.renam`ing the columns:

```
df = df.set_index('UNIQUE_ID')
df = df.rename(columns={'NAME': 1, 'AGE': 2, 'DEP': 3, 'RANK': 4})
```

And finally you can convert the resulting Series back to a DataFrame. The most elegant way to get `COLUMN NO` at the right place is using [`df.rename_axis`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303913/new-index-level-name-after-dataframe-stack) before stacking. All together as one expression (possibly better to split it up):

```
>>> (df.set_index('UNIQUE ID')
       .rename(columns={'NAME': 1, 'AGE': 2, 'DEP': 3, 'RANK': 4})
       .rename_axis('COLUMN NO', axis=1)
       .stack()
       .to_frame('NAME')
       .reset_index())

    UNIQUE ID  COLUMN NO    NAME
0           1          1   John
1           1          2      10
2           1          3    4th
3           1          4       1
4           2          1  Priya
5           2          2      11
6           2          3    4th
7           2          4       2
8           3          1   Jack
9           3          2      15
10          3          3    5th
11          3          4       2
12          4          1   Jill
13          4          2      14
14          4          3    5th
15          4          4       1
```

Things left out: reading the data; preserving the correct type: `UNIQUE ID` only looks numeric, but has leading zeros that probably want to be preserved; so parsing them as a string would be better.

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much. It worked perfectly.

Comment: No thanks needed - but it is custom here to *accept* a helpful/best answer using the checkmark (below the voting buttons) next to the answer. But glad it works